# AJAX call outerHTML uncaught typeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When implementing this code in CMS environment. Getting beloe error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of undefined

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

**Main.html:**

```
<div class="pwrapper">
                  <select name="country" id="scountry">
                    <option id="EN" value="global.html">GLOBAL, ENGLISH</option>
                    <option id="AU" value="australia.html">AUSTRALIA</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function ()  {                       
                      $('.country #scountry').on('change', function(e){
                          var ajaxURL = $(this).val();
                          $.ajax({
                              url: ajaxURL,
                              success: function(data) {
                                  var htmlData = $(data);
                                   $('#scontainer').html(htmlData.filter('#ajax-container').get(0).outerHTML);
                              }
                          });                          
                      });                          
                      $('.countrySelector #scountry').trigger('change');
                  });
              </script>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
 <section class="no-padding">
     <div id="scontainer">
     </div>
 </section>
</div>
```

**global.html (Under main.html as child page):**

```
<div id="ajax-container">
   Hello World!!
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't `$('#scontainer').html(data);` work?

Comment: You don't need outerHTML... just insert the jQuery object . If it is the only element in root of what is returned... insert `data` and no need to filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
htmlData.filter('#ajax-container').get(0).outerHTML
```

with this code

```
htmlData.find('#ajax-container').html();
```

Comment: instead of that : htmlData.filter('#ajax-container').get(0).outerHTML

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal case for using `load()` which is a shortcut method for `$.ajax`.

You could replace your current `$.ajax` request and callback with:

```
$('#scontainer').load(ajaxURL +' #ajax-container);
```

The space separated selector after the url is used to determine which fragments of requested html response to insert in the container. If the only root element returned is the id you want, you don't need any filtering for fragments and can remove the fragment selector

Reference: [load() docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)